# Scala: reflection and case classes

Tags: scala, reflection, shapeless, case-class, scala-reflect

The following code succeeds, but is there a better way of doing the same thing? Perhaps something specific to case classes? In the following code, for each field of type String in my simple case class, the code goes through my list of instances of that case class and finds the length of the longest string of that field.

```
case class CrmContractorRow(
                             id: Long,
                             bankCharges: String,
                             overTime: String,
                             name$id: Long,
                             mgmtFee: String,
                             contractDetails$id: Long,
                             email: String,
                             copyOfVisa: String)

object Go {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = CrmContractorRow(1,"1","1",4444,"1",1,"1","1")
    val b = CrmContractorRow(22,"22","22",22,"55555",22,"nine long","22")
    val c = CrmContractorRow(333,"333","333",333,"333",333,"333","333")
    val rows = List(a,b,c)

    c.getClass.getDeclaredFields.filter(p => p.getType == classOf[String]).foreach{f =>
      f.setAccessible(true)
      println(f.getName + ": " + rows.map(row => f.get(row).asInstanceOf[String]).maxBy(_.length))
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
bankCharges: 3
overTime: 3
mgmtFee: 5
email: 9
copyOfVisa: 3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do this kind of thing with Shapeless, I'd strongly suggest defining a custom type class that handles the complicated part and allows you to keep that stuff separate from the rest of your logic.

In this case it sounds like the tricky part of what you're specifically trying to do is getting the mapping from field names to string lengths for all of the `String` members of a case class. Here's a type class that does that:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.labelled.FieldType

trait StringFieldLengths[A] { def apply(a: A): Map[String, Int] }

object StringFieldLengths extends LowPriorityStringFieldLengths {
  implicit val hnilInstance: StringFieldLengths[HNil] =
    new StringFieldLengths[HNil] {
      def apply(a: HNil): Map[String, Int] = Map.empty
    }

  implicit def caseClassInstance[A, R <: HList](implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    sfl: StringFieldLengths[R]
  ): StringFieldLengths[A] = new StringFieldLengths[A] {
    def apply(a: A): Map[String, Int] = sfl(gen.to(a))
  }

  implicit def hconsStringInstance[K <: Symbol, T <: HList](implicit
    sfl: StringFieldLengths[T],
    key: Witness.Aux[K]
  ): StringFieldLengths[FieldType[K, String] :: T] =
    new StringFieldLengths[FieldType[K, String] :: T] {
      def apply(a: FieldType[K, String] :: T): Map[String, Int] =
        sfl(a.tail).updated(key.value.name, a.head.length)
    }
}

sealed class LowPriorityStringFieldLengths {
  implicit def hconsInstance[K, V, T <: HList](implicit
    sfl: StringFieldLengths[T]
  ): StringFieldLengths[FieldType[K, V] :: T] =
    new StringFieldLengths[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
      def apply(a: FieldType[K, V] :: T): Map[String, Int] = sfl(a.tail)
    }
}
```

This looks complex, but once you start working with Shapeless a bit you learn to write this kind of thing in your sleep.

Now you can write the logic of your operation in a relatively straightforward way:

```
def maxStringLengths[A: StringFieldLengths](as: List[A]): Map[String, Int] =
  as.map(implicitly[StringFieldLengths[A]].apply).foldLeft(
    Map.empty[String, Int]
  ) {
    case (x, y) => x.foldLeft(y) {
      case (acc, (k, v)) =>
        acc.updated(k, acc.get(k).fold(v)(accV => math.max(accV, v)))
    }
  }
```

And then (given `rows` as defined in the question):

```
scala> maxStringLengths(rows).foreach(println)
(bankCharges,3)
(overTime,3)
(mgmtFee,5)
(email,9)
(copyOfVisa,3)
```

This will work for absolutely any case class.

If this is a one-off thing, you might as well use runtime reflection, or you could use the `Poly1` approach in Giovanni Caporaletti's answer—it's less generic and it mixes up the different parts of the solution in a way I don't prefer, but it should work just fine. If this is something you're doing a lot of, though, I'd suggest the approach I've given here.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll have to come back to this when I've mastered Shapeless!

Comment: Don't wait until then! I'm not sure anyone's mastered Shapeless!

Comment: nice, much better than mine!

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti But not so concise, unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use shapeless to get the string fields of a case class and avoid reflection you can do something like this:

```
import shapeless._
import labelled._

trait lowerPriorityfilterStrings extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[A] = at[Vector[(String, String)], A] { case (acc, _) => acc }
}

object filterStrings extends lowerPriorityfilterStrings {
  implicit def caseString[K <: Symbol](implicit w: Witness.Aux[K]) = at[Vector[(String, String)], FieldType[K, String]] {
    case (acc, x) =>  acc :+ (w.value.name -> x)
  }
}

val gen = LabelledGeneric[CrmContractorRow]


val a = CrmContractorRow(1,"1","1",4444,"1",1,"1","1")
val b = CrmContractorRow(22,"22","22",22,"55555",22,"nine long","22")
val c = CrmContractorRow(333,"333","333",333,"333",333,"333","333")
val rows = List(a,b,c)

val result = rows
  // get for each element a Vector of (fieldName -> stringField) pairs for the string fields
  .map(r => gen.to(r).foldLeft(Vector[(String, String)]())(filterStrings))
  // get the maximum for each "column"
  .reduceLeft((best, row) => best.zip(row).map {
    case (kv1@(_, v1), (_, v2)) if v1.length > v2.length => kv1
    case (_, kv2) => kv2
  })

result foreach { case (k, v) => println(s"$k: $v") }
```

Comment: I'm keeping the strings here but you can easily replace them with their lengths

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use Scala reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val rm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val instanceMirrors = rows map rm.reflect
typeOf[CrmContractorRow].members collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor && m.returnType =:= typeOf[String] =>
    val maxValue = instanceMirrors map (_.reflectField(m).get.asInstanceOf[String]) maxBy (_.length)
    println(s"${m.name}: $maxValue")
}
```

So that you can avoid issues with cases like:

```
case class CrmContractorRow(id: Long, bankCharges: String, overTime: String, name$id: Long, mgmtFee: String, contractDetails$id: Long, email: String, copyOfVisa: String) {
  val unwantedVal = "jdjd"
}
```

Cheers

Comment: This is the one I will probably use! At least until I understand Shapeless.

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code to something more reuseable:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class CrmContractorRow(
                             id: Long,
                             bankCharges: String,
                             overTime: String,
                             name$id: Long,
                             mgmtFee: String,
                             contractDetails$id: Long,
                             email: String,
                             copyOfVisa: String)

object Go{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = CrmContractorRow(1,"1","1",4444,"1",1,"1","1")
    val b = CrmContractorRow(22,"22","22",22,"55555",22,"nine long","22")
    val c = CrmContractorRow(333,"333","333",333,"333",333,"333","333")
    val rows = List(a,b,c)
    val initEmptyColumns = List.fill(a.productArity)(List())

    def aggregateColumns[Tin:ClassTag,Tagg](rows: Iterable[Product], aggregate: Iterable[Tin] => Tagg) = {

      val columnsWithMatchingType = (0 until rows.head.productArity).filter {
        index => rows.head.productElement(index) match {case t: Tin => true; case _ => false}
      }

      def columnIterable(col: Int) = rows.map(_.productElement(col)).asInstanceOf[Iterable[Tin]]

      columnsWithMatchingType.map(index => (index,aggregate(columnIterable(index))))
    }

    def extractCaseClassFieldNames[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag] = {
      scala.reflect.classTag[T].runtimeClass.getDeclaredFields.filter(!_.isSynthetic).map(_.getName)
    }

    val agg = aggregateColumns[String,String] (rows,_.maxBy(_.length))
    val fieldNames = extractCaseClassFieldNames[CrmContractorRow]

    agg.map{case (index,value) => fieldNames(index) + ": "+ value}.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Using shapeless would get rid of the .asInstanceOf, but the essence would be the same. The main problem with the given code was that it was not re-usable since the aggregation logic was mixed with the reflection logic to get the field names.